# Apply patch TortoiseHg code error 255

Tags: tortoisehg

i have TortoiseHg on Windows and i have add a repository the problem is that if I try to apply a patch with this comdand Repository-Impost-File Patch i received the error 255..

The repository is update and program work correctly without this patch

Comment: Patch can not be applied cleanly for a lot of reasons. Did you try to "Show details" in Import dialogue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do when a patch for Mercurial import fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591928/what-to-do-when-a-patch-for-mercurial-import-fails)